# How to extend Flask-admin model Edit and Create templates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-admin

according to the [flask-admin docs](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/) I can extend the main flask-admin dashboard by creating the file `templates/admin/index.html` and extending `admin/master.html`. The HTML would look like this:

```
{% extends 'admin/master.html' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>HELLO</h1>
{% endblock body %}
```

But i can't find any information on how to extend the model CRUD pages: **List, Edit and Create**. I need to extend the Create and Edit User page so i can add js code to the form template.

Is there a template where i can extend just like `admin/master.html` example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found it in [flask-admin docs](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/#working-with-the-built-in-templates).  I had to  create `templates/edit_user.html` and `templates/create_user.html`. For `list_users` is also the same, theres is an example in the docs.

In `edit_user.html`

```
{% extends 'admin/model/edit.html' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>User Edit View</h1>
    {{ super() }}
{% endblock %}
```

In `create_user.html`

```
{% extends 'admin/model/create.html' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Create View</h1>
    {{ super() }}
{% endblock %}
```

and then add this to the User model View:

```
class UserView(ModelView):
    edit_template = 'edit_user.html'
    create_template = 'create_user.html'


admin.add_view(UserView(User, db.session))
```

Answer (score 0):

As for [DOC](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/#adding-model-views), this is the default command:

```
admin = Admin(app, name='microblog', template_mode='bootstrap3')
```

> Add your own CSS here /static/css/main.css:

```
{% block head_css %}
  {{ super() }}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css', _external=True) }}" ></link>
{% endblock %}
```